# Starting AWS DynamoDB Local from Eclipse STS on OSX

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-tool-suite

I'm trying to use DynamoDB Local from the AWS Explorer from Eclipse (STS 3.4.0) on OSX.

I've set region to "Local", but I get an error message popping up saying:

> An internal error occurred during: "Updating contents". Unable to
>   create client: Unknown service endpoint: `http://localhost:8000`

The [docs](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/8048104791011805) mention that I should be able to "select "Start DynamoDB Local" from the DynamoDB node's context menu", but I see no such option.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse. An [updated](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Eclipse/8124018805590366) version was released today. If you have configured Amazon DynamoDB Local in the toolkit, it should be working again. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me - now I can right-click the node and go through the Create Table wizard, but the table never gets created and displays an error dialogue of "Unable to create the table: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection to http://localhost:8000 refused".

Comment: My bad - I wasn't using a 1.7 JDK. Now it won't start, but with this error: "UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-x86_64 in java.library.path"

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB Local needs to be running (the idea is that it will run locally and mimic the AWS DynamoDB service, but I supposed it could be running anywhere accessible to your PC). The following command is used to start it (from the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html)):

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar
```

By default, the service listens on port 8000, but that can be modified using the --port switch:

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar --port 8001
```

From your error message, it does sound like an attempt is being made to connect to the default port (8000) for the DynamoDB Local service.  Are you sure that the service is running, or that you haven't started it on a different port?

See Jeff Barr's post [here](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/09/dynamodb-local-for-desktop-development.html) for additional detail.

Comment: The docs say "You can now install and run the DynamoDB Local Test Tool from within Eclipse. To start the test tool, open the AWS Explorer, change the region to "Local", and select "Start DynamoDB Local" from the DynamoDB node's context menu," which made me think it can be started from Eclipse itself. If that's not the case, then the docs are rather rubbish :)

Comment: perhaps they should say "You can now use the DynamoDB Local Test Tool from within Eclipse"....

Is it working for you now?